# Laravel, syntax error, unexpected '::' in controller when trying to fetch data from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am Trying to fetch some data for my DB by following the example shown in [Laravels documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent).

But for some reason i get syntax error, unexpected '::' in HomeController.php on line 15.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\News;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $news = new::all(); // <---------------------- This line
        return view ('home', ['news' => $news]);
    }
}
```

And here is the model if needed

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class News extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'news';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'text'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `new` is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) and can not be used as a class.
2. Your class is called `News`, not `new`. So change `new::all();` to `News::all();`.

Comment: Thanks!
So you recommend changing new to a different name?

Comment: Your class is named `News` and that's fine. No need to change that.

Comment: So only if the class name interface with a reseved word i get those problems?

Comment: See the link in my answer.